# Emit from single when flowable emits

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an activity where you can see a bunch of places according to a filter and the current viewport of the map.

So I've modeled these two sources as `Flowables`:

```
fun boundariesFlowable(): Flowable<Pair<LatLon, LatLon>>
fun filtersFlowable(): Flowable<FilterRequest>
```

Where boundaries emits the TopLeft and BottomRight corners of the map viewport, and filters just emits any change in the filters applied by the user.

Now I want to observe these two sources so that a call is performed each time either of them changes. This is my request call:

```
 fun refreshApplyFilter(id: Int, filter: FilterRequest): Single<FilterResponse>
```

The problem, I cannot figure out how to combine this trigger sources, or how to perform the call on their emission.

I've tried flatmapping just one of the sources but it expects a `Publisher`, while my request is a `Single`.

Comment: could you please share your stream definition? specially where subsscription happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flowable.combineLatest()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator to observe several sources. If any of them post new value, function will be triggered.

```
val res: Flowable<FilterResponse> = Flowable.combineLatest(boundariesFlowable(), filtersFlowable(), BiFunction<Pair<LatLon, LatLon>, FilterRequest, FilterRequest> { pair, filter ->
    filter
}).flatMapSingle { filter -> refreshApplyFilter(0, filter) }
```

Comment: combineLatest helps me combine them indeed, thanks! However refreshApplyFilter returns a Single and cannot be returnd there (I think? I am getting an error anyway): Not enough information to infer parameter. I could explicitly specify <Pair,FilterRequest,Single<FilterResponse>> but then I would be returning a Single object instead of its result

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin, I've updated answer to satisfy your requirements

Comment: that did the trick thanks, still need to get my head around these rxjava operators